# IntelliJ read remote server log file

Tags: logging, intellij-idea, remote-access, remote-server, logfile

Do you have any idea how can I setup my Remote configuration to display a log file on the server instead of on my local machine?

On the edit configuration screen (Logs tab) I have the option to show a log file, but only logs from my machine, not from the remote server.

[image]

I don't mind if I have to install any plugin for it, but until now I couldn't find any that did what I want.

Thanks!

Comment: Having a same situation here. Did you find out how to do it?

Comment: I didn't find a solution yet, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

See [this](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13-log4jplugin) JetBrains plugin. I've just installed it myself. You can create a remote debug session from Intellij with your server and than point the logs with Log4JPlugin.

For remote debug connections check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114066/attach-intellij-idea-debugger-to-a-running-java-process)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can track your logs directly via SSH

```
ssh your_server tail -f /to/your/log_file
```