# Load Text Input File IntelliJ and debug

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

How can I debug a project in IntelliJ Idea while capturing input from a text file? I can load the project like so from Terminal:

java -jar tm.jar < wants.txt

I want the capability step into/debug code while looping over the text file content.

Answer (score 1):

You can use remote debug functionality in IntelliJ by adding some JVM arguments to your application. You can also see more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114066/attach-intellij-idea-debugger-to-a-running-java-process).