# How do I debug Apache Flink?

Tags: debugging, apache-flink

I've been working on expanding the Apache Flink Python API to better match the Java API and I get weird errors about the types of the data I am working on. Is there a way to attach a Java debugger (e.g. Intellij IDEA) to debug Flink itself?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Google for "Java Remote debug command line"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to [Svetlin Zarev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2588800/svetlin-zarev) for pointing out remote Java debugging. Here are some helpful things I should've found before asking:

1. Set up remote debugging in IDE/debugger/whatever e.g. for [IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21114066/3246662)
2. Modify Apache Flink JVM arguments by [setting env.java.opts in the configuration](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/setup/config.html) using the appropriate settings for remote debugging

Or to debug Flink job runners, set up remote debugging and run the job using `bin/flink` with `JVM_ARGS` set in your environment. Make sure to set `JVM_ARGS` only for `bin/flink` and not for the Flink job manager (i.e. `bin/start-local.sh`) or the ports will clash.

I've made a little fish shell function that wraps Flink job run so that the proper arguments are set [here](https://gist.github.com/GEOFBOT/8d0c84a323a1da4e61ab8ef695929d51).