# Intellij - How to edit JVM command line arguments for remote debugging

Tags: java, debugging, tomcat, intellij-idea

I want to use a custom class loader which supports hot-swapping (DCEVM). I've set up a remote debug configuration. To enable the classloader, I have to edit a command line, as described here: https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent

```
-XXaltjvm=dcevm -javaagent:PATH_TO_AGENT\hotswap-agent.jar
```

The problem is that the **"command line arguments for running remote JVM" textbox in IntelliJ is read-only**. Is it possible to somehow override the command line? I tried to inject those arguments in a "Port" textbox but it seems that it's validated...

I use IntelliJ 2017.1 Community Edition.

The question appeared in comments to  [Attach Intellij-IDEA debugger to a running java process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114066/attach-intellij-idea-debugger-to-a-running-java-process/30793101), but remained unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, IntelliJ IDEA only suggests you the options that are needed to enable remote debugging. All the other options for your app should be added manually to the command line when JVM is started.

Comment: So, if hot swapping fails, it means that there is an error in a command line which I use to start tomcat.