# Breakpoints not working on IntelliJ Ultimate

Tags: java, debugging, tomcat, intellij-idea, breakpoints

I am new to IntelliJ and I am trying to set up environment. I use latest version of IntelliJ and Tomcat. When I make an api request using Postman, the breakpoints on IntelliJ are not being hit. I have configured Tomcat locally and when I run the server in debug mode I do not get any error and the application runs as expected. But I want to debug my application and breakpoints on IntelliJ do not work. Any help will he highly appreciated.

Resolved: I deleted the entire project and set it up from scratch. And this helped.

Thanks everyone for your suggestions:)

Comment: Are you running Tomcat from within IntelliJ?

Comment: What  run configuration are you running under? Are you setting your tomcat port in the remote settings in IntelliJ? Go to Run->Edit Configurations -> Click the green plus-> Select Remote -> and type in your local host tomcat port.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attach Intellij-IDEA debugger to a running java process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114066/attach-intellij-idea-debugger-to-a-running-java-process)

Comment: @avaz yes I am running Tomcat from within IntelliJ.

Comment: @DevelopingDeveloper Thank you. The issue is resolved. I created new project.I did not have to set tomcat port in remote settings. But will keep in mind this option if I run into the same issue in future. :)

Comment: @HSAR Please add your resolution as an answer for others with this problem in the future.