# Remote debug docker+wildfly with intelliJ 2017.2.6

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, wildfly, remote-debugging

So there are a lot of posts around this subject, but none of which seems to help.

I have an application running on a wildfly server inside a docker container.
And for some reason I cannot connect my remote debugger to it.

So, it is a wildfly 11 server that has been started with this command:

```
/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0 -c standalone.xml --debug 9999;
```

And in my standalone.xml I have this:

```
<socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
```

The console output seems promising:
`Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9999`

I can even access the admin console with the credentials admin:admin on `localhost:9990/console`

However IntelliJ refuses to connect... I've creates a remote JBoss Server configuration that in the server tab points to localhost with management port 9990.
And in the startup/connection tab I've entered 9999 as remote socket port.

The docker image has exposed the ports 9999 and 9990, and the docker-compose file binds those ports as is.

Even with all of this IntelliJ throws this message when trying to connect:

```
Error running 'remote':
Unable to open debugger port (localhost:9999): java.io.IOException "handshake failed - connection prematurally closed"
```

followed by

```
Error running 'remote':
Unable to connect to the localhost:9990, reason:
com.intellij.javaee.process.common.WrappedException: java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to remote+http://localhost:9990. The connection failed
```

I'm completely lost as to what the issue might be...

Interessting addition is that after intelliJ fails, if I invalidate caches and restart then wildfly reprints the message saying that it is listening on port 9999

Comment: >"I've creates a remote JBoss Server configuration that in the server tab points to localhost with management port 9990."

For the host field you should specify the remote interface that is accessible from your pc where IDE will deploy the artifact.

Comment: >"And in the startup/connection tab I've entered 9999 as remote socket port."

There you should copy the command line for *Debug* mode and use it to start the remote VM. Then use JBoss Remote Run/Debug configuration to connect to started remote VM. See the JBoss configuration [Server tab for a remote configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-jboss-server.html#d526148e401) for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this can be seen as an answer since it goes around the problem.
But the way I solved this, was by adding a "pure" remote configuration in intelliJ instead of jboss remote. This means that it won't automagically deploy, but I'm fine with that

Comment: That's helpful... I am having the exact same problem with my dockerized wildfly project. Could you explain how you configured the "pure" remote configuration?

Comment: Long time since I did it towards wildfly, but fairly sure that it is not too far from normal. So have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114066/attach-intellij-idea-debugger-to-a-running-java-process

Answer (score 4):

In case someone else in the future comes to this thread with he same issue, I found this solution here:
https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/wildfly/issues/91#issuecomment-450192272

Basically, apparart from the --debug parameter, you also need to pass *:8787

Dockerfile:

```
CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0", "--debug", "*:8787"]
```

docker-compose:

```
ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    - "8787:8787"
    - "9990:9990"
command: /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0 --debug *:8787
```

I have not tested the docker-compose solution, as my solution was on dockerfile.