# How to remote debug Vespa in standalone mode?

Tags: vespa

How do I remote debug vespa in standalone mode?
Especially the custom components like Searchers, Processors?

Answer (score 4):

Please take a look at [the container documentation](http://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/performance/profiling-search-container.html#idea) for remote debugging with IntelliJ IDEA. First, set up a remote debugging configuration in IDEA as shown in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30793101/4897413). Then, add the jvm arguments to the `container/nodes` element in your `services.xml`:

```
   <container id='default' version='1.0'>
      <search/>
      <document-api/>
      <nodes jvmargs='-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 -Dvespa.freezedetector.disable=1'>
          <node hostalias='node1'/>
      </nodes>
   </container>
```

Just make sure the port numbers in IDEA and `services.xml` match.