# Unable to open debugger in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.7

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, connectexception

I am unable to open debugger in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.7 and getting the error message-
"Unable to open debugger port(localhost:57226):java.net.ConnectException" "Connection refused:connect"

I tried changing the port number from Run/Debug Configurations,however i am still getting the same error.

Comment: What Run/Debug configuration type do you use?

Comment: Please find the Run/Debug Configuration below:Debugger mode:Attach,Host:localhost ,port:5005..For JDK1.4x:-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005

Comment: Is it Remote configuration? Did you start the process with the suggested options? Can you verify that it listens for debugger connection on the specified port and this port is not taken by some other app? Do you debug on the same machine?

Comment: Yes it is remote configuration.How do i start the process with the suggested options-pls let me know.

Comment: Copy/paste the options suggested by IntelliJ IDEA into the command line where you start the app to enable debug mode. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/30793101/104891.

Comment: i tried this but it still gives the same error- "Unable to open debugger port(localhost:57226):java.net.ConnectException" "Connection refused:connect"

Comment: Check with TcpView that the app listens for the debugger on the specified port. Disable the firewall.