# Generating logs from application with Intellij Remote Debugging

Tags: logging, intellij-idea, slf4j, remote-debugging

I'm trying to set up Intellij to generate logs on my local computer for an application that I'm remotely debugging. That is, I run remote debugging on an application that's in production, and as I use it, the log file is generated on my local machine.  I've followed the instructions for remote debugging [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114066/attach-intellij-idea-debugger-to-a-running-java-process), and am now following the instructions for the logging [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/setting-log-options.html).  However, when I run the debugger, the log file generated on my Desktop is empty.  Here are my settings:

[image]

I've set it up to have the same name as the file it would generate on the server.  I'm also using `slf4j` to log.  So far, I've had no luck in getting any output to testLog on my local computer.

Comment: Do you get proper output in console if you don't use Logs?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Were you able to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

same problem here, proper settings in LOG tab. On server side log is OK by

> tail -f /your/path/your.log

Do you have line before connect? :

```
Console output is saving to: /home/path_to_log/Documents/free_log.txt
```

Comment: If you have same issue, you can: [ask your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) question, or just edit this one to make it "bump". But don't post issue as answer, it should be a comment. Also, this question seems inactive, so I don't know if you will receive an answer...