# How right connect remote debugging to Tomcat using IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

I have 2 ready 'war' Java package (backend + frontend) running on Tomcat under my windows PC.
Also, I have project source codes (unfortunately I can't build and run debug it's from source because I don't have access to the special repository).

How i can connect from IDE to Tomcat for debugging running java threads?

Thank you!

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-jboss-server.html

Comment: Have you tried Tomcat remote: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-tomcat-server.html?

Comment: @y.bedrov  - thank you. But yours link don't help me.
And was added in "%Tomcat_home%\bin\catalina.bat" next string: 
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xdebug -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005" 
This is working under windows - tomcat print in console: "Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005". I was use method from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114066/attach-intellij-idea-debugger-to-a-running-java-process/43186456#43186456) for connect from IDEA.    But i still don't understand - how i can join source and debagging war sources. ((