# azure functions debuging error in intelliJ IDE

Tags: java, azure, debugging, intellij-idea, azure-functions

I can not debuging my function in intelliJ IDE. 
I follow this guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-maven-intellij) but I got error of:

> 11:50 Error running 'Function debug': Unable to open debugger port (localhost:5005): java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused: connect"

I tried change port but nothing

-----EDITED-----------
short content from idea.log:

```
2019-10-03 15:13:32,126 [36052271]  ERROR - ationJsonSchemaProviderFactory - IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.3  Build #IU-183.5153.38 
2019-10-03 15:13:32,126 [36052271]  ERROR - ationJsonSchemaProviderFactory - JDK: 1.8.0_152-release; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2019-10-03 15:13:32,126 [36052271]  ERROR - ationJsonSchemaProviderFactory - OS: Windows 10 
2019-10-03 15:13:32,129 [36052274]  ERROR - ationJsonSchemaProviderFactory - Last Action: ShowLog 
2019-10-03 15:13:32,130 [36052275]  ERROR - ationJsonSchemaProviderFactory - Configuration type "Apache Spark on Cosmos Serverless" is not valid: factory list is empty 
java.lang.Throwable: Configuration type "Apache Spark on Cosmos Serverless" is not valid: factory list is empty
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:134)
    at com.intellij.configurationScript.RunConfigurationJsonSchemaGenerator.generate(RunConfigurationJsonSchemaGenerator.kt:303)
    at com.intellij.configurationScript.IntellijConfigurationJsonSchemaProviderFactoryKt$generateConfigurationSchema$$inlined$json$lambda$1.invoke(IntellijConfigurationJsonSchemaProviderFactory.kt:83)
    at com.intellij.configurationScript.IntellijConfigurationJsonSchemaProviderFactoryKt$generateConfigurationSchema$$inlined$json$lambda$1.invoke(IntellijConfigurationJsonSchemaProviderFactory.kt)
    at com.intellij.configurationScript.JsonObjectBuilder.mapOrArray(JsonBuilder.kt:93)
    at com.intellij.configurationScript.JsonObjectBuilder.rawMap(JsonBuilder.kt:79)
    at com.intellij.configurationScript.IntellijConfigurationJsonSchemaProviderFactoryKt.generateConfigurationSchema(IntellijConfigurationJsonSchemaProviderFactory.kt:82)
    at com.intellij.configurationScript.IntellijConfigurationJsonSchemaProviderFactory$schemeContent$2.invoke(IntellijConfigurationJsonSchemaProviderFactory.kt:27)
    at com.intellij.configurationScript.IntellijConfigurationJsonSchemaProviderFactory$schemeContent$2.invoke(IntellijConfigurationJsonSchemaProviderFactory.kt:25)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
    at com.intellij.configurationScript.IntellijConfigurationJsonSchemaProviderFactory.getSchemeContent(IntellijConfigurationJsonSchemaProviderFactory.kt)
    at com.intellij.configurationScript.IntellijConfigurationJsonSchemaProviderFactory.access$getSchemeContent$p(IntellijConfigurationJsonSchemaProviderFactory.kt:25)
    at com.intellij.configurationScript.IntellijConfigurationJsonSchemaProviderFactory$MyJsonSchemaFileProvider$schemeFile$1.invoke(IntellijConfigurationJsonSchemaProviderFactory.kt:45)
    at com.intellij.configurationScript.IntellijConfigurationJsonSchemaProviderFactory$MyJsonSchemaFileProvider$schemeFile$1.invoke(IntellijConfigurationJsonSchemaProviderFactory.kt:43)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
    at com.intellij.configurationScript.IntellijConfigurationJsonSchemaProviderFactory$MyJsonSchemaFileProvider.getSchemaFile(IntellijConfigurationJsonSchemaProviderFactory.kt:59)
    at com.jetbrains.jsonSchema.impl.JsonSchemaServiceImpl.getSchemaForProvider(JsonSchemaServiceImpl.java:486)
    at com.jetbrains.jsonSchema.impl.JsonSchemaServiceImpl.access$700(JsonSchemaServiceImpl.java:35)
    at com.jetbrains.jsonSchema.impl.JsonSchemaServiceImpl$MyState.createFileProviderMap(JsonSchemaServiceImpl.java:469)
    at com.jetbrains.jsonSchema.impl.JsonSchemaServiceImpl$MyState.access$600(JsonSchemaServiceImpl.java:407)
    at com.jetbrains.jsonSchema.impl.JsonSchemaServiceImpl$MyState$1.compute(JsonSchemaServiceImpl.java:421)
    at com.jetbrains.jsonSchema.impl.JsonSchemaServiceImpl$MyState$1.compute(JsonSchemaServiceImpl.java:416)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ClearableLazyValue.getValue(ClearableLazyValue.java:48)
    at com.jetbrains.jsonSchema.impl.JsonSchemaServiceImpl$MyState$1.getValue(JsonSchemaServiceImpl.java:427)
    at com.jetbrains.jsonSchema.impl.JsonSchemaServiceImpl$MyState$1.getValue(JsonSchemaServiceImpl.java:416)
    at com.jetbrains.jsonSchema.impl.JsonSchemaServiceImpl$MyState.getFiles(JsonSchemaServiceImpl.java:449)
    at com.jetbrains.jsonSchema.impl.JsonSchemaServiceImpl.isMappedSchema(JsonSchemaServiceImpl.java:293)
    at com.jetbrains.jsonSchema.impl.JsonSchemaServiceImpl.isMappedSchema(JsonSchemaServiceImpl.java:289)
    at com.jetbrains.jsonSchema.impl.JsonSchemaServiceImpl.isSchemaFile(JsonSchemaServiceImpl.java:283)
    at com.jetbrains.jsonSchema.ide.JsonSchemaService.isSchemaFile(JsonSchemaService.java:29)
    at com.jetbrains.jsonSchema.impl.JsonSchemaRegexInjector.getLanguagesToInject(JsonSchemaRegexInjector.java:23)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.injected.InjectedPsiCachedValueProvider$MyInjProcessor.process(InjectedPsiCachedValueProvider.java:77)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.injected.InjectedLanguageManagerImpl.processInPlaceInjectorsFor(InjectedLanguageManagerImpl.java:410)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.injected.InjectedPsiCachedValueProvider.doCompute(InjectedPsiCachedValueProvider.java:57)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.injected.InjectedLanguageUtil.probeElementsUp(InjectedLanguageUtil.java:340)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.injected.InjectedLanguageUtil.enumerate(InjectedLanguageUtil.java:167)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.injected.InjectedLanguageManagerImpl.enumerateEx(InjectedLanguageManagerImpl.java:308)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LineMarkersPass.queryLineMarkersForInjected(LineMarkersPass.java:223)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LineMarkersPass.queryProviders(LineMarkersPass.java:185)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LineMarkersPass.lambda$doCollectInformation$3(LineMarkersPass.java:96)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.Divider.divideInsideAndOutsideInOneRoot(Divider.java:79)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LineMarkersPass.doCollectInformation(LineMarkersPass.java:91)
    at com.intellij.codeHighlighting.TextEditorHighlightingPass.collectInformation(TextEditorHighlightingPass.java:69)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$null$1(PassExecutorService.java:423)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1168)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$doRun$2(PassExecutorService.java:416)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:582)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:532)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:87)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.doRun(PassExecutorService.java:415)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$run$0(PassExecutorService.java:391)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ReadMostlyRWLock.executeByImpatientReader(ReadMostlyRWLock.java:147)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.executeByImpatientReader(ApplicationImpl.java:222)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.run(PassExecutorService.java:389)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl$VoidForkJoinTask$1.exec(JobLauncherImpl.java:161)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
2019-10-03 15:13:32,131 [36052276]  ERROR - ationJsonSchemaProviderFactory - IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.3  Build #IU-183.5153.38 
2019-10-03 15:13:32,131 [36052276]  ERROR - ationJsonSchemaProviderFactory - JDK: 1.8.0_152-release; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2019-10-03 15:13:32,131 [36052276]  ERROR - ationJsonSchemaProviderFactory - OS: Windows 10 
2019-10-03 15:13:32,132 [36052277]  ERROR - ationJsonSchemaProviderFactory - Last Action: ShowLog 
2019-10-03 15:13:32,132 [36052277]  ERROR - aemon.impl.PassExecutorService - Array is empty. 
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Array is empty.
    at kotlin.collections.ArraysKt___ArraysKt.first(_Arrays.kt:864)
    at com.intellij.configurationScript.RunConfigurationJsonSchemaGenerator.generate(RunConfigurationJsonSchemaGenerator.kt:74)
    at com.intellij.configurationScript.IntellijConfigurationJsonSchemaProviderFactoryKt$generateConfigurationSchema$$inlined$json$lambda$1.invoke(IntellijConfigurationJsonSchemaProviderFactory.kt:83)
    at com.intellij.configurationScript.IntellijConfigurationJsonSchemaProviderFactoryKt$generateConfigurationSchema$$inlined$json$lambda$1.invoke(IntellijConfigurationJsonSchemaProviderFactory.kt)
    at com.intellij.configurationScript.JsonObjectBuilder.mapOrArray(JsonBuilder.kt:93)
```

Comment: Do you use any antivirus software that might block connections?

Comment: I canceled it but nothing

Comment: Could you please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue?

Comment: @y.bedrov I added short content. I used thread in timerTrigger functions. is it doing the problem of debuging? thanks!

Comment: Did "mvn azure-functions:run -DenableDebug" start fine?

Comment: I updated idea.log according to what is now. run is ok but in degub mode not

Comment: It looks like plugin issue. Please report plugin vendor: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8053-azure-toolkit-for-intellij/

Comment: I uninstall Azure Toolkit for IntelliJ but without changes. the error message is appears. in vs code ide the debugging work great.

Comment: Are there any errors/warnings in log when you run without plugin?

Comment: same thing. in running mode it is okey when in debug is fall down

Answer (score 0):

There are two additional resources below which I think may help for you.

1. The offical GitHub wiki page about [`Debugging Azure Functions Host and Java Worker`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/wiki/Debugging-Azure-Functions-Host-and-Java-Worker)
2. A related SO thread [Attach IntelliJ IDEA debugger to a running Java process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114066/attach-intellij-idea-debugger-to-a-running-java-process) is refered by the wiki page above for IntelliJ IDE about `Add debug configuration in IntelliJ`.

Hope it helps.