# How to debug remote spring boot appliaction in IntelliJ Ultimate with gradle project tool

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I am new to IntelliJ and gradle and I want to debug my Spring boot application remotely , request is coming from UI and I need to debug the request ,
But not getting success , tried many thing followed JetBrain site and also tried to configure the debug setup.

but I m really getting frustrated, I guess I am not starting server in debug mode or doing something wrong.

Could anyone tell me how to set up the configuration in IntelliJ with Gradle Spring project?

[image]

getting error like:
Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8082): java.io.IOException "handshake failed - connection prematurally closed"

[image]

Edit: do I need to do anything else , my app is running on 8082 port no.
I am running my app normally as I do via cmd line ./gradlew bootRun

Comment: You need to set some JVM flags to enable debugging on the Java process. This should allow you to attach IntelliJ using the _Remote_ run configuration. Please review the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114066/attach-intellij-idea-debugger-to-a-running-java-process

Comment: Please see if https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-remote-debug.html help.

Comment: Yes i have tried the same but getting error like "Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8082): java.io.IOException "handshake failed - connection prematurally closed""

Comment: What Java version do you use? Try launching with JDK 8. Here is a related issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-173607 .

Answer (score 2):

Unless you made some modifications to the *Gradle* build configuration (which I doubt being the case since you mentioned being new to *Gradle*), you should be able to start you application with a debugger attached to it using the `--debug-jvm` flag:

```
$ ./gradlew run --debug-jvm
```

and since you are using *Spring Boot*, you should rather use the `bootRun` task:

```
$ ./gradlew bootRun --debug-jvm
```

Once above command fired, your application will start and you should see below line in output:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
```

stating that the JVM debugger is waiting for a client to attach on port `5005` which should be the same as your *IntelliJ IDEA | Remote JVM Debug* configuration port. Change the port from `8082` to `5005` for your *Store_Debug* configuration then click on the  icon and you should see a message stating that your debugger is attached:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:5005', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: You're welcome :)